# How to run MongoDB multiple queries under a transaction in Stitch?

Tags: mongodb, transactions, mongodb-stitch

I'm working on a react-native project which uses MongoDB as database and need to run multiple Insert & Update operations atomically. I need to run the operations under a transaction but as I use MongoDB Stitch functions for db operations and expose them to my app via a Stitch http service, I couldn't find any solution about using transactions in MongoDB Stitch on the internet. Is this possible at all?

Comment: I saw your post yesterday then received this [Mongo Transactions Webinar](https://www.mongodb.com/webinar/mongodb-transactions-webinar-series) announcement today. Thought it might help. It's not clear if they will address Stitch specifically.

Answer (score 1):

Transactions are [unsupported in Stitch](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/mongodb/mongodb-service-limitations/index.html#notable-unsupported-features).